# Azure Cosmos DB - Azure DocumentDB Data Migration Tool - Not able to export large database (4gb) to json file

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, offset

**Requirement:**
We have to migrate Azure Cosmos DB data (4gb) to Azure SQL.

**Progress until now:**
Following this article [Use Data migration tool to migrate your data to Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data) we downloaded and installed the migration tool. When we try to export data from a sample cosmos db database (having few records) it works as expected. that is output Json file is generated.
however when trying to export data from production Cosmos DB database (4 GB) after 1 hour 17 minutes we get below error

[Error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXcGg.png)

A task was canceled.

**Trials from our side:**
Suspecting that it is to do with large database size to be exported, we tried to export a portion of data by setting the select query as

```
Select * From C OFFSET 1 LIMIT 100
```

However this query throws error saying incorrect syntax near OFFSET. but this query works in Azure Cosmos DB query editor.

Kindly let know what we are doing wrong/missing.

Comment: I run into the same issue. The tool allows you to select Azure Cosmos DB as the "source", so it should allow a query that has the correct syntax (like OP, I tried running the query in the query editor and it runs fine.):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVbNT.png

And yet it gives an error message when trying to use the offset limit clause.

Answer (score 0):

The tool you are using is for migrating from an SQL database to CosmosDB.

From your question it sounds like you are trying to do the oposite. That is probably why it does not work.

Comment: Shiraz thanks for your quick reply. In the said Microsoft white paper in this section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#export-to-json-file it speaks about exporting cosmos DB data in  json file. this is what we are trying.